# SQL recursive CTE returns more results than expected

Tags: sql, entity-framework, recursion, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Using SQL I'm trying to get a list of ids of a user's descendants. So, say I have:

```
Id | ManagerId | Name
---|-----------|------
4  | NULL      | James Smith
7  | 4         | John Doe (1)
8  | 7         | John Doe (2)
9  | 8         | John Doe (3)
10 | 8         | John Doe (4)
```

And I want to get back `4, 7, 8, 9, 10`. Looking around online the recommended approach is to create a recursive CTE, which I've done as:

```
WITH UsersCTE AS (
    SELECT  Id,
            ManagerId
    FROM    Users
    WHERE   IsActive = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.Id,
            UsersCTE.Id
    FROM    UsersCTE
            INNER JOIN Users AS A
                ON A.ManagerId = UsersCTE.ManagerId
)

SELECT  *
FROM    UsersCTE;
```

Which kind of works. It starts out by getting the ids that I want, and then just goes off and starts getting ids in all kind of manners. I'll confess that I have no idea how it works, but it's not giving me the result I want. Instead it's giving me this:

[image]

How can I get it to give me just the ids I want. For reference, I need to get this list so I can then query back the db and get a list of orders for the current users and any descendants they manage. I am using EF6 for the data access and was planning on making this CTE into a view and querying it appropriately, but I'm open to better recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as follows:

```
WITH UsersCTE AS (
    SELECT  Id,
            ManagerId
    FROM    Users
    WHERE   IsActive = 1 and ManagerID is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.Id,
            UsersCTE.Id
    FROM    UsersCTE
            INNER JOIN Users AS A
                ON A.ManagerId = UsersCTE.Id and A.IsActive = 1
)

SELECT  *
FROM    UsersCTE;
```

The null filter in the first part anchors your CTE i.e. gives it a base case of employees with no managers. The other change is in the join condition of the second part. The updated condition matches manager ID to employee ID.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GAOCD41643)

Comment: Ahhh, I see. It makes sense now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You probably want to repeat `WHERE IsActive = 1` in the recursive member.